# Como saber la URL de mi reporte Jasper

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft

tengo un servidor de informes de Jasper, ingreso sin problemas, tengo un reporte creado, pero cuando lo llamo de mi servicio me dice que la dirección URL no se encuentra, alguna sabe cual sería la dirección.
Le he anota esta :

"http://192.168.100.76:8080/jasperserver/root/reports/" + "reporteJasper"
y me da error.

"http://192.168.100.76:8080/jasperserver/reports/" + "reporteJasper". lo he hecho de esta manera pero igual me da error.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/192.168.100.76:8080/jasperserver/root/reports/ProgramacionDA (No such file or directory)

como será la dirección??

Adjunto una imagen donde esta el reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public String generateReport() {
        try {

            List<ProgramacionModel> items = new ArrayList<ProgramacionModel>();
            repository.findAll(Sort.by("fecProgramacion").ascending()).forEach(items::add);
            System.out.println("ESTAMOS ANTES DE LA RUTA");
            System.out.println(new JSONObject(items.get(1)));

            /** Servidor de informes */
             String reportPath = "http://192.168.100.76:8080/jasperserver/root/Reports/";

            /** Informes locales */
            //String reportPath = "/Users/jvalvarez/JaspersoftWorkspace/Bitzu/MyReports/";

            // Compile the Jasper report from .jrxml to .japser
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(reportPath + "ProgramacionDA.jrxml");

            // Get your data source
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(items);
            System.out.println("ESTAMOS DESPUES DE LA RUTA");
            System.out.println(items);
            // Add parameters
            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

            parameters.put("createdBy", "Ing. Álvarez Rojas");
            System.out.println(parameters);
            // Fill the report
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                    null,
                    jrBeanCollectionDataSource);
            System.out.println("ESTAMOS DESPUES DE JasperPrint");
            // Export the report to a PDF file
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, reportPath +
                    "\\ReporteProgramacionDA.pdf");

            System.out.println("Done");

            return "Report successfully generated @path= " + reportPath;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ESTAMOS EN EL CATCH");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: La URL no funcionará mientras no se llame dentro una sesión de jasperserver. Una alternativa es invocar el reporte desde un alguno de los [webservices de jasperserver](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v62/introduction).

Comment: Yo lo estoy invocando desde spring-boot, edite el mensaje para que lo vea, lo puse debajo de la imagen.

Comment: JasperServer no es un servidor de archivos .jrxml/.jasper, aunque sí tiene un repositorio que puede almacenar .jrxml; JasperServer puede hacer por ti lo que hace tu código: compilar y ejecutar, pero tienes que invocarlo como un servicio web. Lo que tu haces es una ejecución independiente (stand-alone) y para eso prácticamente no necesitas JasperServer.

Comment: Tienes algún ejemplo como para guiarme??

Lo que necesito es invocar o llamar mi reporte y mostrarlo en pantalla.

Hay otros reportes que llevan algún parámetro, pero de momento no estoy consumiendo unos de esos.